# Repairing one column RPT File in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm import data from Microsoft SQL server, Here's my code

`df = pd.read_table("Some_data.rpt")`

when I print `df` , the result

```
    ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD ColumnE`
0             ------ ------ ----- ----- ---
1                           896 578 AC 73 8
2                           976 782 AD 78 9
3                           763 678 AC 52 8
```

And `df.shape` give output `(245237,1)`. My questions how to make format table like

```
    ColumnA  ColumnB  ColumnC  ColumnD ColumnE
0    ------   ------    -----    -----     ---
1       896      578       AC       73       8
2       976      782       AD       78       9
3       763      678       AC       52       8
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe there is scope to clean up "Some_data.rpt" i.e exporting data as csv format from SQL server itself. then it would be much cleaner. If .rpt is not in your control, then pls post some data which you have on "Some_data.rpt"

Comment: Can you post the content of the file corresponding to the sample, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to define your seperator. Try with a space:

```
df = pd.read_table("Some_data.rpt", sep=" " )
```

Comment: Works for my questions, but still can't repair my actual file

Comment: If this works - why do you need to repair?

Comment: My actual file have address etc, that contain non consistent amont of space, but currently I download the file as CSV

Comment: Then post an example